# Using MultiResourceItemReader with jsonItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: json, spring-batch

I have multiple .json files to read from my classpath (/resources/input/*.json) in my Spring Batch application. Below is the my code:

```
@Value("${search.folder}")
private Resource[] inputResources;

@Bean
 public MultiResourceItemReader<Trade> multiResourceItemReader() {

        return new MultiResourceItemReaderBuilder<Trade>()
                    .delegate(jsonItemReader())
                    .resources(inputResources)
                    .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<Trade> jsonItemReader() {

        logger.info("In Item reader method to read the file.");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JacksonJsonObjectReader<Trade> jsonObjectReader =
                new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Trade.class);

        jsonObjectReader.setMapper(objectMapper);

        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Trade>()
                .jsonObjectReader(jsonObjectReader)
                .resource(new ClassPathResource(inputResources))
                .name("tradeJsonItemReader")
                .build();

    }

application.yml

search:
  folder: input\*.json
```

THe exception which I am getting is:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader]: Factory method 'jsonItemReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A resource is required.

From the above exception I do understand that a resource is required in jsonItemReader. But how do I give a resource in jsonItemReader() as the resource is already coming from MultiResourceItemReader.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine: Thanks the link provided by you answers my question. I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Resource resource(@Value("#{jobParameters['DIRECTORY_PATH']}") String directoryPath) {
    return new FileSystemResource(directoryPath);
}
```